# Haddop cluster have 3 live nodes but just 1 node active in resource manager

Tags: docker, hadoop, hdfs

I run hadoop on docker with apache/hadoop image from docker hub.

i just run with the default configuration and add 2 mode datanodes

Here my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "2"
services:
   namenode:
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      hostname: namenode0
      command: ["hdfs", "namenode"]
      ports:
        - 9870:9870
      env_file:
        - ./config
      environment:
          ENSURE_NAMENODE_DIR: "/tmp/hadoop-root/dfs/name"
   datanode-0:
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      command: ["hdfs", "datanode"]
      env_file:
        - ./config
   datanode-1:
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      command: ["hdfs", "datanode"]
      env_file:
        - ./config
   datanode-2:
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      command: ["hdfs", "datanode"]
      env_file:
        - ./config
   resourcemanager:
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      hostname: resourcemanager
      command: ["yarn", "resourcemanager"]
      ports:
         - 8088:8088
      env_file:
        - ./config
      volumes:
        - ./test.sh:/opt/test.sh
   nodemanager:
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      command: ["yarn", "nodemanager"]
      env_file:
        - ./config
```

but in the namenode UI there is 3 live node
[image: there is 3 live nodes]

If run this

```
$ hdfs dfsadmin -report

Configured Capacity: 763068678144 (710.66 GB)
Present Capacity: 405373390848 (377.53 GB)
DFS Remaining: 405373366272 (377.53 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Replicated Blocks:
        Under replicated blocks: 0
        Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
        Missing blocks: 0
        Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
        Low redundancy blocks with highest priority to recover: 0
        Pending deletion blocks: 0
Erasure Coded Block Groups: 
        Low redundancy block groups: 0
        Block groups with corrupt internal blocks: 0
        Missing block groups: 0
        Low redundancy blocks with highest priority to recover: 0
        Pending deletion blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (3):

Name: 172.25.0.4:9866 (hadoop_datanode-0_1.hadoop_default)
Hostname: 7eb5f69ae955
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 254356226048 (236.89 GB)
DFS Used: 8192 (8 KB)
Non DFS Used: 115378343936 (107.45 GB)
DFS Remaining: 135124455424 (125.84 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 53.12%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 0
Last contact: Sat Oct 07 15:43:14 UTC 2023
Last Block Report: Sat Oct 07 15:21:42 UTC 2023
Num of Blocks: 0


Name: 172.25.0.5:9866 (hadoop_datanode-1_1.hadoop_default)
Hostname: 29d464fd39ac
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 254356226048 (236.89 GB)
DFS Used: 8192 (8 KB)
Non DFS Used: 115378343936 (107.45 GB)
DFS Remaining: 135124455424 (125.84 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 53.12%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 0
Last contact: Sat Oct 07 15:43:13 UTC 2023
Last Block Report: Sat Oct 07 15:21:37 UTC 2023
Num of Blocks: 0


Name: 172.25.0.7:9866 (hadoop_datanode-2_1.hadoop_default)
Hostname: dccb08fe06b8
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 254356226048 (236.89 GB)
DFS Used: 8192 (8 KB)
Non DFS Used: 115378343936 (107.45 GB)
DFS Remaining: 135124455424 (125.84 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 53.12%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 0
Last contact: Sat Oct 07 15:43:12 UTC 2023
Last Block Report: Sat Oct 07 15:21:42 UTC 2023
Num of Blocks: 0
```

but there is just 1 node acctive in yarn and resource manager

```
$ yarn node -list

2023-10-07 15:47:05 INFO  DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider:64 - Connecting to ResourceManager at resourcemanager/172.25.0.6:8032
Total Nodes:1
         Node-Id             Node-State Node-Http-Address       Number-of-Running-Containers
c8ac8dd71a0d:41135              RUNNING c8ac8dd71a0d:8042                                  0
```

[image]

how to add the other node to active node ?

Comment: Are you required to use HDFS over Ozone or MinIO, which work much better in Docker environments?

Answer (score 0):

Datanodes and Nodemanagers are two different things. Add more Nodemanager to update YARN

Keep in mind that your system may eventually run out of memory trying to run all those containers, and there's really no point since it's still a single point of failure (your host) and competing with the same set of resources (CPU, hard drive and RAM), so all those containers are likely to be slower than installing Hadoop locally and giving it full access to your system, rather than forcing it to replicate data within the same hard drive and make internal ("fake remote") network calls from the same host

Comment: So if I can make 3 nodes active in YARN, that will get the same result if I used it? Because they all in same machine ?

Comment: YARN automatically creates multiple JVM containers to run tasks. You do not need multiple NodeManager or ResourceMangers processes on one machine, whether in a container, or not